# Communication between two modules in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is rather simple to imagine, but I haven't found any resources mentioning what is correct approach to this issue.

I'd like to broadcast event in one angular **module** and receive it in another one. Those two  modules are totally different, with different code base and purpose. The only thing that they have in common is the fact that they are running in a website on the same domain (might be important due to the same origin policy).

I know this is possible, for instance by synchronizing events via HTML5's Local Storage. I just want to know how to do it properly.

Comment: Are they sharing an instance of the angular object?

Comment: Nope. They do not share any state other than Local Storage objects.

Answer (score 7):

### "Properly"

I will begin by describing the aspect of *scales* of an application in order to provide clarity in what to implement to *"properly"* achieve this.

First, You have an *application* that is running on a *server*, contains a *core* which encapsulates *modules*. The lower-level you go from here could consist of either *more modules* or *controllers*. I will address both.

Prerequisites include but are not limited too:

- Implementing Angular *scope-events* for controllers (if necessary)
- Implementing the [Mediator Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) to spec.
- Implementing a *SharedWorker* with custom events.
- Implementing an *Event-Hub* on the server side (if necessary)

If you need a communication-network between your *controllers*, use the standard Angular `$scope` & `$rootScope` `.$broadcast`, `.$emit`, and `.$on` utilities inside your *module(s)* -- you probably already thought of this ;)

To communicate between *modules*, implement the Mediator Pattern in your *core* -- probably, this will be implemented as a Service that each module can pull in; otherwise, your modules can be initialized & provided a sandbox with *Mediator/Director* injected. Now your *modules* within your *application-core* can communicate.

Say, you need this *application* / *core* to communicate with another *application*. Implement a *SharedWorker with custom events*. You can see a framework, ["worker.io" I built for UCLA here](https://github.com/cScarlson/worker.io). The project could use some touching up, so feel free to use it as a reference to write your own -- **the point to focus on** is that it uses *Pseudo Port-Entanglement*. This is because workers only allow an `onmessage` handler, so you want to create a `new MessageEvent`; send it as a JSON String to the other port, and then JSON.parse` the message to get the custom event and dispatch that event on the port that received the event -- this gives you custom events. Now, any application can utilize this *SharedWorker* and communicate to other apps through it -- it even allows for communication ***between browser tabs***.

If you want a more global approach to an *Event-Driven Architecture*, say, to give modules on the *server* a chance to respond to events (from anywhere) -- implement an *event-hub* on your server. This can be more of a project than you'd like to embark on, but a great book exists which describes how to set this up: [Testable JavaScript, Mark Ethan Trostler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449323391).

That said, it is completely possible to elegantly implement a highly-optimized architecture for Event-Based Systems using *Mediators*, *SharedWorkers*, and *EventHubs* on the back-end.

The *worker.io* framework noted above uses two libraries: *Apis* (Bee in latin), and *Scriptorium* (Hive in latin). However, to see how to implement the libraries, see the [js directory](https://github.com/cScarlson/worker.io/tree/master/js).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

> I just want to know how to do it properly.

"Properly" is pretty subjective. "Properly" is whatever works, is easy to understand and is maintainable.

That said, why not just use `$window` to pass the values between the two separate running angular apps?

```
function persistFoo($scope, $window) {
   //watch window.foo
   $scope.$watch(function (){
      return $window.foo;
   }, function(v) {
      if($scope.foo !== v) {
         $scope.foo = v;
      }
   });

   //watch scope.foo
   $scope.$watch('foo', function(v) {
      if($window.foo !== v) {
         $window.foo = v;
      }
   });
}

//Module 1
app1.controller("MyCtrl1", function($scope, $window) {
  persistFoo($scope, $window);
});

//Module 2
app2.controller("MyCtrl2", function($scope, $window) {
  persistFoo($scope, $window);
});
```

localStorage will work too, if you need to persist the data for subsequent visits.

Comment: AFAIK this won't work when two modules are in separate browser tabs, right? I could probably get away with grabbing `opener` instance, since one module "opens" another. 

When I say "properly" I have in mind some solution which would be advised/supported by framework itself. If no such method exists, I would go for "any working solution" which does not validate any existing standards of doing things (formal or informal).

Comment: If they're in two separate browser tabs, you're not really going to be able to do it easily on the client. localStorage may work, other than that, you're looking at possibly persisting something back to the server.

Comment: So your question is 'How to exchange messages between two distinct angular applications sharing same domain while being loaded into two separate browser tabs'?

Comment: You're going to have to persist it back to the server and push it back out, or try localStorage checked on an interval.

Comment: Aside from the 'window barrier' -- which is actually more of a *port barrier* (each browser window & tab has its own port) -- this is not a good idea, to say the least. As ***Coupling* is the most dangerous form of Software Entropy**, **you have just suggested doing the 2nd worst thing possible to a software system**: *Common Coupling*. Read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming).

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled about a similar problem. Here is a plunker which show how to solve a problem like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uk7ODSbgXfzqw0z6x4EH?p=preview

```
var app1 = angular.module('App1', []);

app1.controller('App1Controller', function($scope) {

    // use this function to send a value to app2
    var sendText = function(newText) {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('app2')).scope().setText(newText);
    };

    $scope.$watch('text', function(newText) {
        sendText(newText);
    });

    // initial value
    $scope.text = "Some text";
});

/*

 The code above and below do not share any module, service, etc.

*/


var app2 = angular.module('App2', []);
app2.controller('App2Controller', function($scope) {

    // this function will be called from app1 when text changes
    $scope.setText = function(newText){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.text = newText;
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: Message passing through the View unnecessarily and awkwardly couples the two modules, and is bad practice.