# How to get the latest data from a module that is updated from another module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 AngularJS modules, `M` a module to be the **model** holder/manager, and another 2 modules `app` which is the main module and `A` which will manipulate data of `M` module. Both `app` and `A` have dependency on `M`.

For simplicity, the model is just an array of animals names, and I want to add new names from within module `A` those I expect to see reflected within the list controlled by `app` module.

This [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/rtuejbnm1EjgMuLzvROB?p=preview) illustrates the case.

I implemented the Mediator Pattern as suggested in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365517/236384) so my model module `M` will publish its changes to its subscribers.

`app` has a controller `NamesListCtrl` that reads data from `NamesModel` the factory from `M`, and subscribes to its event `NamesModelChanged` that is published whenever the inner data inside `NamesModel` is changed.

**The problem**: when the anonymous callback for `NamesListCtrl` subscription to `NamesModelChanged` is called (line 87 in plunk), the statement `$scope.data.namesList = NamesModel.getAll();` will not retrieve the updated data:

```
NamesModel.subscribe('NamesModelChanged', function() {
  console.log('OK, I will update my data');
  // not getting the updated list
  $scope.data.namesList = NamesModel.getAll();
});
```

Any help?

Comment: it appears as though the problem here is that your `NamesModel` is a factory rather than a service.  Each time the factory is injected, the function that the factory runs is returned, which means that you have more than one list.  When `App Module` hears the publish, it calls the `getAll` function on it's own *instance* of the function the factory returns, while `Module A` updates a different *instance*.  A service wouldn't have this issue, since services are singletons, meaning there can only ever be one instance.

Comment: and yes, I understand that factories are also singletons, but really all that means is that the same function is always returned, but the function is still called multiple times, once per controller that injected it, so each get an identical (at app startup) version of the object the factory returns, but still individual instances.

Answer (score 0):

At that time when controller and model will initialize and page was loading, you will need to intialize $scope.data.namesList variable and assign a data inti this, by $scope.data.namesList = NamesModel.getAll(); , then when ever you will call it, it will return updated data, conclusion is, when you create scope variable initially you need to make it real time live object/variable.

Answer (score 0):

Two things got it solved:

1) The `publish` called from within the `NamesModel` factory should include `list` so the `subscribe` callback in other controllers will get the fresh data, so assuming the callback named the published list as `newList`, just calling `$scope.data.namesList = newList` will update the data in `NamesListCtrl`.

2) Then `$scope.$digest()` need to be called to force the UI to refresh.

Here is the new working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/r9QPFm?p=preview)

Thanks [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies), and [Jigar Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4336065/jigar-prajapati) for your help.